# CakePHP 3.6.17: Eager loading with sorting

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, eager-loading, model-associations

I want to combine eager loading with sort by in cakephp 3.6

Ιn my controller I can use eager loading or sort by but I can't combine them. Here is my code:

Eager loading:

```
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => [ 'TasksTo' => ['ProjectStatus']]
    ]); 
    $this->set(compact('user'));
```

Sort:

```
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['TasksTo'  => ['sort' => ['TasksTo.priority' => 'ASC']]]); 
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

both work as expected when used separately but not together. How I can combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I fixed it like this:

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['TasksTo' => ['ProjectStatus', 'sort' => ['TasksTo.priority' => 'ASC']]]); 
$this->set(compact('user'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation. Assuming ProjectStatus is linked to TasksTo, try this:

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['TasksTo.ProjectStatus' => ['sort' => ['TasksTo.priority' => 'ASC']]]); 
$this->set(compact('user'));
```

Comment: actually its not working...If I add `.ProjectStatus` I can see status but then ordering doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix that?